# How many flags does this site receive daily on average?

Tags: support, moderators

[This answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1060/2995) says:

> Additional moderators can also be requested by the moderators of a site, if they feel that there is a need to increase the mod team size (which is usually when there's a large queue at hand, continually for a few months). (And **no, it does not depend on traffic, but rather the size of the moderator queue**).

So what is the size of moderator queue for this site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Over the past year, our average is about 1 flag every 6 days.  Over the past quarter, it's about 1 flag every 3 days.  Bottom line, our moderator queue is very small, and there are three of us.  So we are nowhere near at capacity.

Comment: It will be better if it is updated for recent days.